# why 0, not Nothing in VB System.Data.DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

The codes:

```
        Private m_log_dataTable As System.Data.DataTable = Nothing
        Private m_freq As String = Nothing
        Private m_r As Single = Nothing
        Private m_l As Single = Nothing
        Private m_c As Single = Nothing
        Private m_rp As Single = Nothing
        Private m_rs As Single = Nothing
        Private m_z As Single = Nothing
        Private m_esr As Single = Nothing
        Private m_dcr As Single = Nothing
        Private m_q As Single = Nothing
        Private m_d As Single = Nothing
```

...

```
    Private Sub LOG()
        Try
            m_freq = Nothing
            m_r = Nothing
            m_l = Nothing
            m_c = Nothing
            m_rp = Nothing
            m_rs = Nothing
            m_z = Nothing
            m_esr = Nothing
            m_dcr = Nothing
            m_q = Nothing
            m_d = Nothing
            m_value = Nothing
            m_unit = Nothing
            m_log_dataTable.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now, getDUT(), getMode(), m_freq, m_r, m_l, m_c, m_r, m_rs, m_z, m_esr, m_dcr, m_q, m_d)'Line1
            m_log_dataTable.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now, getDUT(), getMode(), Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)'Line2
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Exception when logging:" + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Output:
[image]

**Why line1 (in the above codes) write 0 to the datatable instead of Nothing?**
What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Is this compiling? `Private m_r As Single = Nothing` is assigning Nothing to a single variable (not a Single?)

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf Yes

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf - this is allowed in VB.NET. It is the same as C# `default(System.Single)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [Nullable type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1). Change all of your `single` types to `single?` and try it again.

```
Private m_r As Single? = Nothing
Private m_l As Single? = Nothing

// etc
```

As Gabor commented, you'll need to access the `Value` property or one of the other methods that are available to `Nullable(Of T)`.

```vb
m_r.Value                 ' Access the underlying value

m_r.GetValueOrDefault()   ' Underlying value or, if none, default for the underlying type

m_r.GetValueOrDefault(3)  ' Underlying value or, if none, some default value you decide
```

Comment: `Nothing` in VB.NET equals to `default(T)` in C# (instead of `null`).

Comment: I got "Nullable variable must have a value" exception

Comment: I assume you call the `m_log_dataTable.Rows.Add()` method with referencing to e.g. `m_freq.Value` instead of just `m_freq`. Or somewhere you try to assign the Value property to a Nullable instance, e.g. `m_something = m_otherthing.Value`

Answer (score 3):

`Nothing` in VB.NET equals to `default(T)` in C# (instead of `null`). Value types cannot be `null` therefore in db they are represented in columns with `not null` constraint.

You indeed should use `Nullable(Of Single)` (which is the same as `Single?`) for your fields.

But of course this is not enough. You should modify the columns in the database so that they will have `null` constraint instead of `not null` and the `System.Data.DataTable` should be configured the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Coz The default value of Single is 0.You can use string column or you can define target datagridview's columns.

```
DataGridViewCellStyle1.Format = "N"
Column1.DefaultCellStyle = DataGridViewCellStyle1
```